# Need Top Level 301 Redirect but subdomain has same name as redirect?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301, redirect

I have a main site with multiple subdomains below it:
so:
    example.com
    products.example.com
    books.example.com, etc.

I'm trying to create a redirect like:
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/catalog/(.*) //products.example.com/$1
But this doesn't work because at "products" is a subdirectory/subdomain so it just creates a redirect loop at //products.example.com

```
But This works (because /store isn't //store.example.com/)
RedirectMatch 301 ^/store/catalog/(.*) //products.example.com/$1
```

I tried experimenting with a rewritecond to have it only redirect if the url contains the root domain, but that didn't work either.

If a page like:
    //products.example.com/products/great-thing.html exists and is a subdomain under a main domain installed in a folder "products" (i.e. /public_html/products/...)

```
-- how would you redirect from:
//example.com/products/great-thing.html to 
//products.example.com/products/great-thing.html
```

I hope that makes sense!

I should add that this site is hosted on a managed cloud/vps - so there may very well be something in their setup that is causing trouble.

But at the end of it there seems to be a problem creating redirects when a folder/subdomain exists with the same name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was hard to track down and may have been more of a processwire cms issue than a straight apache redirect issue, but in case it is helpful to someone, what worked was:

Top level (i.e. root domain site) needed for
//example.com/products/great-thing.html to //products.example.com/products/great-thing.html

RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/(.*) https://products.example.com/products/$2 [R=301,L]

which should have gone to:
https://products.example.com/products/great-thing.html
, but instead created a loop which never resolved.

But it does work when on the subsite (processwire) this was added:
RewriteRule ^products/(.*) ^/products/$1 [R=301,L]